# Cat biting me, seems odd

Tags: cats, biting, bonding

So my cat has a strong bond with me. But I notice sometimes he will give me a love bite when I scratch his back or pet his belly. More often it happens when I scratch him. Why does he give me a love bite when I scratch his back? Does he not like being scratched there or what is going on? Before, he wouldn't bite me at all, just purr when I pet his belly or scratched his back.

Answer (score 2):

Properly socialised cats communicate with their butlers. They want food, they will let you know. When they want to be petted, they will get it. But sometimes it can be a bit much, you know. That spot has been properly scratched and is done now. You should stop.

My cats will tell me to stop in the following escalating steps:

1. Move
2. Vocalise (miuow)
3. Growl
4. Put offending thing in its mouth
5. Bite softly
6. But claws into action, but not hard
7. Bite hard
8. Use everything, hard!

With the note that the escalation from #5 can scale fast, in less then 2 seconds to 8. So I had better stop before that.

---

So, I think your cat is communicating that you can stop scratching that spot now, thank you very much.